# Java: String replace doesn't find

Tags: java, string, replace, str-replace

mystring.replace() doesn't find everything in my text e.g:

```
replace = (CalendarInfo.Monday + " " + String.valueOf(dayofmonth) + " " + String.valueOf(CalendarInfo.Month[monthofyear]).toString());
                   str= str.replace(replace, "Hello");
```

I've check the `str` and the `replace` but replace still doesn't do anything! `str` totally have replace string in it.

So why doesn't replace replace!?

Comment: Can you print and write us the value of `str` and `replace` before call `.replace(...)`?

Comment: str = a whole html page and replace is a sentence with about 20 char

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)   says that replace takes in a char and another char, you are providing two strings..The documentation has good examples on usage.. you need some other method?

Comment: @OsamaJaved: CharSequence is allowed too for replace.

Comment: The 1.6 docs sho the CharSequence, the 1.4 doesn't have that method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)  I'd like to see the string your doing the replace on.

Comment: str = htmlcode alot + "Tisdag 17 april" + more html
replace = "Tisdag 17 april"

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "abcd".replace("ab", ""); //str is "cd"
```

That means your code works basically. But your replace string is not exactly in your source string.

Comment: I cannot seperate them with my eye. identical

Comment: @PewLabs: Open both strings in an editor that can show invisible characters (whitespaces, tabulators, ...). Maybe you can't see it.

Comment: no tabs, no extra whitespaces

Comment: @PewLabs: Try replacing the string in your Text Editor and see if it works and copy the strings out of debugger.

Comment: there are identical, I have no clue why it doesn't replace :(

Comment: You can try `String.ReplaceFirst` or `String.ReplaceAll`. But I doubt there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your assumption is wrong.

Maybe different count of (white) spaces, or different code (0x20 or 0xa0), or tab "\011"

Comment: Could be, im loading string from web
Edit* no extra white spaces